# получить совпадения re.search как переменную

Tags: python

всем привет, как получить совпадения в линиях как переменную,

```
pattern_get_GB = r'(\d{1,6}GB)'
for line in first_rep_out.splitlines():
    if re.search(pattern_get_GB, line)
    GB_1.append(first_rep_GB_match)
print(GB_1)
```

уточнение: если в строке найдено совпадение то его нужно записать в переменную и добавить в список, на входе у нас баш комманда, которая идет линиями, в каждой линии я ищу нажные мне данные, если найдено то данные нужно добавить в строку.

PS: про такой вариант знаю:

```
for line in first_rep_out.splitlines():
        res = re.findall(pattern_get_GB, line)
        GB_1.append(res)
    print(GB_1)
```

но в выводе есть пустые строки, как их пропустить?

Comment: кого "его" нужно записать в переменную? Приведите пример данных на входе и то, что хотите получить на выходе

Comment: регулярное выражение нашло совпадение в линии, как результат записать в переменную?

Comment: Вы видимо не понимаете, вам говорят. какое совпадение, какие лини? вы о чем вообще говорите? Непонятно!

Comment: Советую ознакомиться: ["Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример?"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: что-то мне подсказывает, что вам нужно просто: `re.findall(pattern_get_GB, first_rep_out)` безо всяких циклов...

Comment: `но в выводе есть пустые строки, как их пропустить?` - у вас на выходе пустые строки получаются, или в исходном файле пустые строки есть?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если вы не хотите добавлять в список для этого используйте условие перед командой (+ добавил логику если найдётся несколько или не одного совпадения):

```
for line in first_rep_out.splitlines():
    res = re.findall(pattern_get_GB, line)
    for r in res:
        if bool(res[0]):
            GB_1.append(res)
print(GB_1)
```

Также можете отфильтровать полученный список - избавиться от `''`:

```
print(filter(bool, GB_1)
```

Пример выполнения:

```
print(filter(bool, ["", "qwerty"])
# ["qwerty"]
```

Если у вас результат следующий `[[""], ["qwerty"]]` то сначала придётся извлечь из списков:

```
filter(bool, [x.pop() for x in r])
```

Comment: 1. `if bool(res):` - это то же самое что `if res:`, в условии `if` во внутреннем цикле `bool` тоже не нужен. 2. эта проверка излишня, т.к. если список `res` пустой, то цикл не выполнится ни разу. 3. Судя по всему, исходное регулярное выражение не матчит пустую строку (поправьте меня, если я ошибаюсь), поэтому условие во внутреннем цикле не нужно, да и сам внутренний не очень-то нужен.